# Trying to make a function that updates one table and deletes data from another using psql

Tags: sql, function, subquery

I'm working on a project for my class and we were told to make a function that will delete data pertaining to a specific cart number and updates the products table. The function only has one input which is the cart number. Here is what I have:

```
create function clear_cart(text) returns void as
$$

  update products
     set qtyonhand = qtyonhand + (select qty from cart where cart_id = $1)
  where id in (select product_id from cart where cart_id = $1);

  delete from cart where cart_id = $1;

$$ language sql;
```

I've been testing the queries in by directly putting them into psql, and the error I can't seem to get around is on:

```
set qtyonhand = qtyonhand + (select qty from cart where cart_id = $1)
```

It returns multiple values into a field that only accepts one. I've tried looking elsewhere, but I'm not sure where I can find subqueries similar to what I'm trying to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Just in case, here is what the project says:

Parameters: cart_id char

Returns: none

Description: Remove all all items from the specified cart. Adjust the inventory quantities of the products appropriately.

Comment: It seems like you could do with just replacing `qty` with `sum(qty)` in the offending subquery, but [@a_horse_with_no_name's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10579361/297408) (the second suggestion) might be a better alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't show us your datamodel, but from the statements you have given, I'd assume you want something like this:

```
update products
   set qtyonhand = qtyonhand + t.qty
from (select product_id, 
             qty 
      from cart 
      where cart_id = $1) t
where products.id = t.product_id;
```

This assumes that the `cart` table only holds a single row for each product. If that is not the case you'll get that "sub-select returns more than one row as well".

In that case you'll need to apply an aggregate function:

```
update products
   set qtyonhand = qtyonhand + t.total_qty
from (select product_id, 
             sum(qty) as total_qty
      from cart 
      where cart_id = $1
      group by product_id) t
where products.id = t.product_id;
```

Comment: This worked. I didn't think I could use a subquery in the from statement. Thank you very much! Oh, and if it helps, my table looks like this:

create table cart (

cart_id text,

product_id text references products(id),

qty numeric

);

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this with just an UPDATE statement by using something like ON UPDATE CASCADE declared in your table.

So if you have this declared in a table called child. Fk is a reference to a table parent, when that parent gets updated it drops the row in child.

```
FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: That won't solve the problem with the multiple rows returned by the subquery